# Scrollbar is not showing in Scrollview Xamarin Forms 4.6

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Scroll bar is not showing in xamarin form version 4.6

here is my code of .xml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" IsClippedToBounds="True" Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30,0,30,0">
            <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" Source="change_password_image.png" Margin="0,40,0,40" />

            <local:CustomEntry x:Name="txtCurrentPassword" Placeholder="Current Password" TextColor = "White" ReturnType="Next" Keyboard="Text" IsPassword="True" 
               Margin="0,0,0,10"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HeightRequest = "50"  
               PlaceholderColor = "White" 
               BackgroundColor="#c9c9c9"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               FontSize="20"
               />

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>`
```

Comment: I test xamarin forms 4.6, I got the same result like you, I convert my version to 4.4, it worked as normal. Please report this issue in github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues  Thanks.

Comment: I already posted but still no response.

Comment: This issue was added in to-do list in xamarin forms 4.6 before 3 days ago, please refer to this github link https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10882